# Debugging ARM Assembly Context Switch

Tags: c, assembly, arm, raspberry-pi

I'm working on a context switch in ARM v6 assembly. I posted about writing the switch in C, but assembly seems to be safer and more reliable. I've spent a while checking all the offsets and being careful not to delete data from registers, but the context switch just doesn't seem to work properly. I have set up and tested timer interrupts without switching context.

Here's my code:

```
interrupt_asm:
        //store basic interrupt stuff
        sub   lr, lr, #4

//call the interrupt vector
push  { r0-r12 }
mov   r0, lr              @ Pass old pc
bl    interrupt_vector    @ C function
pop   { r0-r12 }

# save_current_thread:
    //remember r1 so you can use it for r0
    push {r1}
    mov r1, r0 //store r0 so it can be restored

    push {r2, r3}
    bl get_current_thread //r0 now has the address of CURRENT_THREAD
    pop {r2, r3}

    add r0, r0, #4 // r0 = &CURRENT_THREAD.r0
    str r1, [r0]   // save what the r0 was

    pop {r1}          // restore r1
    add r0, r0, #4  // r0 = &CURRENT_THREAD.r1
    str r1, [r0]    // save r1

    //r2
    add r0, r0, #4
    str r2, [r0]

    //r3
    add r0, r0, #4
    str r3, [r0]

    //r4
    add r0, r0, #4
    str r4, [r0]

    //r5
    add r0, r0, #4
    str r5, [r0]

    //r6
    add r0, r0, #4
    str r6, [r0]

    //r7
    add r0, r0, #4
    str r7, [r0]

    //r8
    add r0, r0, #4
    str r8, [r0]

    //r9
    add r0, r0, #4
    str r9, [r0]

    //r10
    add r0, r0, #4
    str r10, [r0]

    //r11
    add r0, r0, #4
    str r11, [r0]

    //r12
    add r0, r0, #4
    str r12, [r0]

    //store SVC sp, lr, and pc
    mrs r1, cpsr
    bic r1, r1, #0x1F
    orr r1, r1, #0x13
    msr cpsr_c, r1

    //sp
    add r0, r0, #4
    str sp, [r0]

    //lr
    add r0, r0, #4
    str lr, [r0]

    //back to IRQ land
    mrs r1, cpsr
    bic r1, r1, #0x1F
    orr r1, r1, #0x12
    msr cpsr_c, r1

    //pc THIS NEEDS TO BE LR 
    add r0, r0, #4
    str lr, [r0]

    //cpsr
    add r0, r0, #4
    mrs r1, cpsr
    str r1, [r0]

    //spsr
    add r0, r0, #4
    mrs r1, spsr
    str r1, [r0]

push {r2, r3}
bl increment_thread //r0 now has the address of our next thread
pop  {r2, r3}

# restore_thread:
    //were pushing in order, so from the bottom up our stack is: r0, ... r12, sp, lr, pc, spsr
    add r0, r0, #4 //r0 = &CURRENT_THREAD.r0
    ldr r1, [r0] //r1 = thread.r0
    push {r1}

    add r0, r0, #4
    ldr r1, [r0] //r1 = thread.r1
    push {r1}

    add r0, r0, #4
    ldr r1, [r0] //r1 = thread.r2
    push {r1}

    add r0, r0, #4
    ldr r1, [r0] //r1 = thread.r3
    push {r1}

    add r0, r0, #4
    ldr r1, [r0] //r1 = thread.r4
    push {r1}

    add r0, r0, #4
    ldr r1, [r0] //r1 = thread.r5
    push {r1}

    add r0, r0, #4
    ldr r1, [r0] //r1 = thread.r6
    push {r1}

    add r0, r0, #4
    ldr r1, [r0] //r1 = thread.r7
    push {r1}

    add r0, r0, #4
    ldr r1, [r0] //r1 = thread.r8
    push {r1}

    add r0, r0, #4
    ldr r1, [r0] //r1 = thread.r9
    push {r1}

    add r0, r0, #4
    ldr r1, [r0] //r1 = thread.r10
    push {r1}

    add r0, r0, #4
    ldr r1, [r0] //r1 = thread.r11
    push {r1}

    add r0, r0, #4
    ldr r1, [r0] //r1 = thread.r12
    push {r1}

    add r0, r0, #4
    ldr r1, [r0] //r1 = thread.sp
    push {r1}

    add r0, r0, #4
    ldr r1, [r0] //r1 = thread.lr
    push {r1}

    add r0, r0, #4
    ldr r1, [r0] //r1 = thread.pc
    push {r1}

    add r0, r0, #8 //skip cpsr - agreed 
    ldr r1, [r0] //r1 = thread.spsr
    push {r1}

    //Our stack now looks like spsr, pc, lr, sp, r12, ... r0 (in order of popping)

    pop {r1} //this was the spsr - SPSR 

    pop {lr} //this was the pc   - PC (from thread)

    pop {r2} //this was the lr   - LR (from thread)
    pop {r3} //this was the sp   - SP (from thread)

    //switch to SVC
    mrs r0, cpsr
    bic r0, r0, #0x1F
    orr r0, r0, #0x13
    msr cpsr_c, r0

        msr spsr, r1 //restore spsr
        mov lr, r2   //restore lr to be old lr
        mov sp, r3   //restore sp

    //switch to IRQ
    // mrs r0, cpsr
    // bic r0, r0, #0x1F
    // orr r0, r0, #0x12
    // msr cpsr_c, r0
    cps #0x12

    //our stack now just has the normal registers in it. Restore them
    pop {r12}
    pop {r11}
    pop {r10}
    pop {r9}
    pop {r8}
    pop {r7}
    pop {r6}
    pop {r5}
    pop {r4}
    pop {r3}
    pop {r2}
    pop {r2}
    pop {r1}
    pop {r0}

push  {lr}

ldm   sp!, {pc}^
```

A thread looks like this:

```
typedef struct __attribute__((packed, aligned(8))) {
    void (*run)();
    unsigned r0, r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9, r10, r11, r12, sp, lr, pc;
    unsigned cpsr, spsr;
    unsigned id;
    unsigned priority;
    thread_status status;
    wait_event wait_status;
} thread_t;
```

Do you have any advice about what's going on? An interrupt occurs and it never goes back to a new thread. I've debugged with GDB simulator but can't seem to nail down the issue.

The C function interrupt_vector just does this:

```
 void interrupt_vector(unsigned pc) {
    CURRENT_THREAD.pc = pc; 
    printf("    interrupt vector (pc = 0x%08x | thread.r0 = 0x%08x)\n", pc, CURRENT_THREAD.r0);
    armtimer_clear_interrupt();
}
```

My other C functions are literally one line, and I've looked at their disassembly:

```
void increment_thread(){
    // Not trying to actually increment yet
    __asm__ volatile("mov r0,  %0" : : "r" ((unsigned) &CURRENT_THREAD));
}

void get_current_thread(){
    __asm__ volatile("mov r0,  %0" : : "r" ((unsigned) &CURRENT_THREAD));
}
```

Comment: GDB is not a simulator, it's a debugger. You should single-step (at the instruction level, of course since this is assembly) the code and keep track of the machine state. You should be able to see when it does something unexpected. Pay particular attention to the state right before returning into the new thread.

Comment: Thanks, will get back to you :)

Comment: The first thing I'd do is rework the structure layout to not need all the horrible juggling to create an upside-down stack, then the further mess to restore it. Returning to a new user context needn't be any more complex than "load SPSR and LR with the task PSR and PC, `ldm rX, {r0-r14}^; movs pc, lr`", where rX points at an array of task registers saved in ascending order. And as for the back-and-forth between modes, juggling 2 scratch registers despite having initially stacked the lot, well... Forgive me for not being surprised this is hard to debug - I can't make head nor tail of it :/

Comment: Please take a look at the [arm addressing modes](http://www.davespace.co.uk/arm/introduction-to-arm/addressing.html).  A lot of your code can be made more concise (and then easier for others to understand).  For instance, `STR sp,[r0],#4` would simplify things.  Then if you *go pro*, you will use `ldm` and `stm` instructions which can switch an entire register file at once.  You need to organize the `thread_t` to accommodate this.

Comment: Also, if you have the `cps` instruction, why not use it to switch modes.  It is more concise (for understanding and code density) and needs no scratch register.  The ARM supports both grow down and grow up stacks.  Don't use the `push` and `pop`, but either `ldmia` or `ldmdb` type instructions and you can avoid the juggling of context on the stack (which is also more concise [efficient and understanding]).